# how to send param in react native

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native, parameters, navigation

here I make a login, after successfully logging in I send the id parameter to the home page,
on the home page, I display data based on the login user id. I sent a parameter on the login page.

after that I get the parameter to the home page, but here the results are null.
how to parse the data correctly?

page login

```
 //function login 
    fetch (......)
      .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
              if(responseJson.status == 'ok'){
                this.props.navigation.navigate('home', { id_user: id_user });
              }
              else if(responseJson.status == 'failed') {
              ....
             }


    <Button block info style={styles.mainBtn} onPress={this.login}>
       <Text style={styles.btnText}>Submit</Text>
    </Button>
```

page home

```
componentDidMount(){
      const { params } = this.props.navigation.state; 
      console.log(params)

      const url = 'https://example.com/data?id_user='+params.id_user
      fetch(url)
      .then((response)=> response.json())
      .then((responseJson)=>{
        // console.log(responseJson.data)
          this.setState({
              dataSource: responseJson.data,
              isLoading : false
          })
      })
      .catch((error)=>{
          console.log(error)
      })
  }
```

on the home page, here I want to parse the id data that is being logged,but the results are null when I console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Home` screen, try fetching `id_user` like this in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method.

```js
componentDidMount(){
      const id = this.props.navigation.state.params.id_user
      console.log(id)
      //...rest of the code
}
```

If that doesn't work, configure your `navigation` statement in the `Login` screen like this.

```js
if(responseJson.status == 'ok'){
  this.props.navigation.navigate({'home', { id_user: id_user }});
}
```

Comment: undifine is non objct evaluating this props.route.param

Comment: I have updated the answer now, can you try it out? @HarryWardana

Comment: the results are undifined